# XSLT. Copy node and modify child with name matches variable value

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to copy an element and change the values ​​of those child elements whose name ends with the value of the variable and other child contains specific date value.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet> 
  <xsl:variable name="Date" select="<!--Contains '2019-04-01'"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="CurValue" select="<!--Contains '5.4321'-->"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="CurrCode" select="<!--Contains string 'USD' or 'EUR'-->"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="CurFieldName" select="concat( &apos;U_SFT_&apos; , $CurrCode )"></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <vpf:Msg>      
          <xsl:call-template name="transform"></xsl:call-template>
    </vpf:Msg>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="transform">
    <!--My transform-->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is input xml:

```xml
<BigXml>
...
            <Polish_FX_Vat_Window xmlns="">
                <Code>2019</Code>
                <Name nil="true"/>              
                <Canceled>N</Canceled>
                <Object>SFT_oPolishFX</Object>
                <LogInst nil="true"/>               
                <SFT_POLISHFXVATRCollection>
                    <SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                        <Code>2019</Code>
                        <LineId>25</LineId>
                        <Object>SFT_oPolishFX</Object>
                        <LogInst nil="true"/>
                        <U_SFT_USD>3.745800</U_SFT_USD><!--I need update this field with value $CurVlaue. $CurrCode='USD'-->
                        <U_SFT_EUR>0.000000</U_SFT_EUR>
                        <U_SFT_Date>2019-04-01</U_SFT_Date><!--Date equals $Date variable-->
                    </SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                    <SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                        <Code>2019</Code>
                        <LineId>26</LineId>
                        <Object>SFT_oPolishFX</Object>
                        <LogInst nil="true"/>
                        <U_SFT_USD>13.000000</U_SFT_USD>
                        <U_SFT_EUR>0.000000</U_SFT_EUR>
                        <U_SFT_Date>2019-08-07</U_SFT_Date>
                    </SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                </SFT_POLISHFXVATRCollection>
            </Polish_FX_Vat_Window>
</BigXml>
```

I tried using the `$CurFieldName` variable in the `template match` statement, but that didn't work.

```
             <Polish_FX_Vat_Window xmlns="">
                <Code>2019</Code>
                <Name nil="true"/>              
                <Canceled>N</Canceled>
                <Object>SFT_oPolishFX</Object>
                <LogInst nil="true"/>               
                <SFT_POLISHFXVATRCollection>
                    <SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                        <Code>2019</Code>
                        <LineId>25</LineId>
                        <Object>SFT_oPolishFX</Object>
                        <LogInst nil="true"/>
                        <U_SFT_USD>5.4321</U_SFT_USD><!--New value-->
                        <U_SFT_EUR>0.000000</U_SFT_EUR>
                        <U_SFT_Date>2019-04-01</U_SFT_Date><!--Date equals $Date variable-->
                    </SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                    <SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                        <Code>2019</Code>
                        <LineId>26</LineId>
                        <Object>SFT_oPolishFX</Object>
                        <LogInst nil="true"/>
                        <U_SFT_USD>13.000000</U_SFT_USD><!--Leave value, Date not equals-->
                        <U_SFT_EUR>0.000000</U_SFT_EUR>
                        <U_SFT_Date>2019-08-07</U_SFT_Date>
                    </SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
                </SFT_POLISHFXVATRCollection>
            </Polish_FX_Vat_Window>
```

`$CurrCode` variable can store not even 'EUR' or 'USD' values. The value is determined dynamically in the input.

Comment: @zx485, 
I updated the question. The structure should stay. Different currencies may be present in xml and I need to dynamically determine the fields that need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
<xsl:variable name="CurFieldName" select="concat('U_SFT_', $CurrCode )"></xsl:variable>
```

To change this value, match it in a template (in combination with the *identity template* to copy the rest of your XML).

```
...
<xsl:variable name="Date" select="'2019-04-01'"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="CurValue" select="'5.4321'"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="CurrCode" select="'USD'"></xsl:variable>  <!-- Or 'USD' - can be set dynamically -->
<xsl:variable name="CurFieldName" select="concat('U_SFT_', $CurrCode )"></xsl:variable>
```

In **XSLT-2.0** you can use the variable in the template match rule:

```
<xsl:template match="SFT_POLISHFXVATR/*[name()=$CurFieldName and ../U_SFT_Date=$Date]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="$CurValue" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In **XSLT-1.0** it is a little more complicated and the template encompasses an *all child elements*-rule:

```
<xsl:template match="SFT_POLISHFXVATR/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name()=$CurFieldName and ../U_SFT_Date=$Date">
           <xsl:value-of select="$CurValue" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />                
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In both cases the relevant part of the output looks like

```
...
<SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
    <Code>2019</Code>
    <LineId>25</LineId>
    <Object>SFT_oPolishFX</Object>
    <LogInst nil="true"/>
    <U_SFT_USD>5.4321</U_SFT_USD>
    <!--I need update this field with value $CurVlaue. $CurrCode='USD'-->
    <U_SFT_EUR>0.000000</U_SFT_EUR>
    <U_SFT_Date>2019-04-01</U_SFT_Date>
    <!--Date equals $Date variable-->
</SFT_POLISHFXVATR>
...
```

Comment: Correct. Also, In XSLT 1.0, you could use push style (ie. `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::*[local-name()=$name][namespace-uri()=$uri])]" mode="copy"/><xsl:apply-templates select="*[local-name()=$name][namespace-uri()=$uri]" mode="process">`) besides conditional instructions. **Do note that `name()` function includes prefix, but you don't know to wich namespace uri is bound**

Comment: I had `local-name()` in the first place, but then I noticed that the relevant element is a child of `Polish_FX_Vat_Window xmlns=""`, so I changed it.

Comment: @zx485, Thanks for the help, the answer is very helpful. Maybe you can still help with how to tie this to a date check. And match = "*" also pulls the external <BigXml> in which the one I need is located.

Comment: I updated my answer to include all of the requirements.